# rails 3 - fcgi_handler and dispatcher missing

Tags: apache, ruby-on-rails-3, fastcgi

Im trying to update a 1&1 server to run rails 3 with apache and fastcgi.

Has anyone done this yet?

I the dispatch.fcgi file I have:

```
require 'fcgi_handler'
```

but apparently rails 3 does not have this file any more.

Answer (score 0):

You have the rack gem which has fcgi handler

Comment: I switched to phusion passenger.